# Flot zooming and panning with logarithmic axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to get the zoom and panning working on a Flot plot with a logarithmic x-axis. However, whenever I zoom or pan all the points on the plot vanish and I have to refresh.

Link to jsfiddle is below.  I have the following options set up where I have hard coded the ticks:

```
var options1 = {
    lines: { show: true  },
    yaxis:{
      panRange: [0,6000]  
    },
    xaxis :{
        panRange: [0,20],

            ticks:[0.00000001, 0.0000001, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0],
    transform: function (v) { return Math.log(v); },
    },
    zoom: {interactive: true},

    pan: {interactive: true}

};
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w0wgjcjq/2/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `transform` function you also need an `inverseTransform` function:

```
    inverseTransform: function (v) {
        return Math.exp(v);
    },
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0wgjcjq/4/) or the code snippet below. This is also described in the [Documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes).

```js
var d1 = [
    [20.0000000000000, 6.14194000000000],
    [19.5000000000000, 6.12697000000000],
    [19.0000000000000, 6.10850000000000],
    [18.5000000000000, 6.08726000000000],
    [18.0000000000000, 6.06277000000000],
    [17.5000000000000, 6.03597000000000],
    [17.0000000000000, 6.00640000000000],
    [16.5000000000000, 5.97021000000000],
    [16.0000000000000, 5.94094000000000],
    [15.7500000000000, 5.91888000000000],
    [15.5000000000000, 5.89996000000000],
    [15.2500000000000, 5.88077000000000],
    [15.0000000000000, 5.86918000000000],
    [14.9000000000000, 5.86075000000000],
    [14.8000000000000, 5.85275000000000],
    [14.7000000000000, 5.84439000000000],
    [14.6000000000000, 5.83664000000000],
    [14.5000000000000, 5.82853000000000],
    [14.4000000000000, 5.81990000000000],
    [14.3000000000000, 5.81143000000000],
    [14.2000000000000, 5.80261000000000],
    [14.1000000000000, 5.79600000000000],
    [14.0500000000000, 5.79209000000000],
    [14.0000000000000, 5.78578000000000],
    [13.9000000000000, 5.77702000000000],
    [13.8000000000000, 5.76902000000000],
    [13.7000000000000, 5.76138000000000],
    [13.6000000000000, 5.75354000000000],
    [13.5000000000000, 5.74083000000000],
    [13.2500000000000, 5.72250000000000],
    [13.0000000000000, 5.70458000000000],
    [12.7500000000000, 5.68757000000000],
    [12.5000000000000, 5.66951000000000],
    [12.2500000000000, 5.65803000000000],
    [12.0000000000000, 5.64834000000000],
    [11.7500000000000, 5.64222000000000],
    [11.5000000000000, 5.63983000000000],
    [11.2500000000000, 5.64106000000000],
    [11.0000000000000, 5.64696000000000],
    [10.7500000000000, 5.65821000000000],
    [10.5000000000000, 5.67426000000000],
    [10.2500000000000, 5.69558000000000],
    [10.0000000000000, 5.72321000000000],
    [9.75000000000000, 5.75670000000000],
    [9.50000000000000, 5.79626000000000],
    [9.25000000000000, 5.84289000000000],
    [9.00000000000000, 5.89593000000000],
    [8.75000000000000, 5.95690000000000],
    [8.50000000000000, 6.02513000000000],
    [8.25000000000000, 6.10117000000000],
    [8.00000000000000, 6.18508000000000],
    [7.75000000000000, 6.27698000000000],
    [7.50000000000000, 6.37689000000000],
    [7.25000000000000, 6.48470000000000],
    [7.00000000000000, 6.60040000000000],
    [6.75000000000000, 6.72274000000000],
    [6.50000000000000, 6.85133000000000],
    [6.25000000000000, 6.98514000000000],
    [6.00000000000000, 7.12236000000000],
    [5.75000000000000, 7.26013000000000],
    [5.50000000000000, 7.39634000000000],
    [5.25000000000000, 7.52630000000000],
    [5.00000000000000, 7.64636000000000],
    [4.75000000000000, 7.75244000000000],
    [4.50000000000000, 7.83979000000000],
    [4.25000000000000, 7.89373000000000],
    [4.10000000000000, 7.91961000000000],
    [4.00000000000000, 7.93796000000000],
    [3.90000000000000, 7.95336000000000],
    [3.80000000000000, 7.96682000000000],
    [3.70000000000000, 7.97533000000000],
    [3.60000000000000, 7.97843000000000],
    [3.50000000000000, 7.97856000000000],
    [3.40000000000000, 7.97374000000000],
    [3.30000000000000, 7.96252000000000],
    [3.20000000000000, 7.94537000000000],
    [3.10000000000000, 7.92010000000000],
    [2.98000000000000, 7.88274000000000],
    [2.86000000000000, 7.83863000000000],
    [2.75000000000000, 7.78569000000000],
    [2.63000000000000, 7.72127000000000],
    [2.51000000000000, 7.65161000000000],
    [2.40000000000000, 7.57274000000000],
    [2.28000000000000, 7.48346000000000],
    [2.16000000000000, 7.39663000000000],
    [2.06000000000000, 7.31191000000000],
    [1.96000000000000, 7.23042000000000],
    [1.87000000000000, 7.15334000000000],
    [1.78000000000000, 7.07693000000000],
    [1.69000000000000, 7.00582000000000],
    [1.60000000000000, 6.94620000000000],
    [1.52000000000000, 6.90014000000000],
    [1.45000000000000, 6.86603000000000],
    [1.39000000000000, 6.84318000000000],
    [1.33000000000000, 6.82727000000000],
    [1.27000000000000, 6.82599000000000],
    [1.21000000000000, 6.83266000000000],
    [1.16000000000000, 6.85267000000000],
    [1.10000000000000, 6.87989000000000],
    [1.06000000000000, 6.91617000000000],
    [1.01000000000000, 6.98238000000000],
    [0.930000000000000, 7.04941000000000],
    [0.912011000000000, 7.11896000000000],
    [0.850000000000000, 7.19765000000000],
    [0.831764000000000, 7.27757000000000],
    [0.780000000000000, 7.37045000000000],
    [0.758578000000000, 7.46394000000000],
    [0.715000000000000, 7.56961000000000],
    [0.691831000000000, 7.67386000000000],
    [0.655000000000000, 7.78891000000000],
    [0.630957000000000, 7.90254000000000],
    [0.600000000000000, 8.02545000000000],
    [0.575440000000000, 8.14464000000000],
    [0.550000000000000, 8.27294000000000],
    [0.524807000000000, 8.40808000000000],
    [0.500000000000000, 8.54032000000000],
    [0.478630000000000, 8.69480000000000],
    [0.450000000000000, 8.83135000000000],
    [0.436516000000000, 8.96923000000000],
    [0.410000000000000, 9.10780000000000],
    [0.398107000000000, 9.25962000000000],
    [0.370000000000000, 9.39892000000000],
    [0.363078000000000, 9.49584000000000],
    [0.346737000000000, 9.63759000000000],
    [0.330000000000000, 9.77440000000000],
    [0.316228000000000, 9.90518000000000],
    [0.301995000000000, 10.0312000000000],
    [0.290000000000000, 10.1637000000000],
    [0.275423000000000, 10.3206000000000],
    [0.260000000000000, 10.4510000000000],
    [0.251189000000000, 10.5625000000000],
    [0.239883000000000, 10.6893000000000],
    [0.229087000000000, 10.8073000000000],
    [0.220000000000000, 10.9301000000000],
    [0.208930000000000, 11.0573000000000],
    [0.199526000000000, 11.1743000000000],
    [0.190546000000000, 11.3025000000000],
    [0.180000000000000, 11.4165000000000],
    [0.173780000000000, 11.5151000000000],
    [0.165959000000000, 11.6255000000000],
    [0.158489000000000, 11.7212000000000],
    [0.153000000000000, 11.8264000000000],
    [0.144544000000000, 11.9421000000000],
    [0.138038000000000, 12.0580000000000],
    [0.130000000000000, 12.1568000000000],
    [0.125892000000000, 12.2381000000000],
    [0.120226000000000, 12.3321000000000],
    [0.114815000000000, 12.4243000000000],
    [0.109648000000000, 12.5155000000000],
    [0.104713000000000, 12.5865000000000],
    [0.102000000000000, 12.6739000000000],
    [9.549930000000000E-002, 12.7802000000000],
    [9.120109999999999E-002, 12.8646000000000],
    [8.709640000000000E-002, 12.9487000000000],
    [8.317640000000000E-002, 13.0233000000000],
    [8.000000000000000E-002, 13.1030000000000],
    [7.585780000000000E-002, 13.1882000000000],
    [7.244360000000000E-002, 13.2641000000000],
    [6.918310000000000E-002, 13.3396000000000],
    [6.606930000000000E-002, 13.4129000000000],
    [6.309570000000000E-002, 13.4985000000000],
    [5.900000000000000E-002, 13.5712000000000],
    [5.754400000000000E-002, 13.6284000000000],
    [5.495410000000000E-002, 13.7005000000000],
    [5.248080000000000E-002, 13.7694000000000],
    [5.011870000000000E-002, 13.8408000000000],
    [4.786300000000000E-002, 13.9159000000000],
    [4.570880000000000E-002, 13.9987000000000],
    [4.300000000000000E-002, 14.0673000000000],
    [4.168690000000000E-002, 14.1217000000000],
    [3.981070000000000E-002, 14.1938000000000],
    [3.801890000000000E-002, 14.2691000000000],
    [3.630780000000000E-002, 14.3410000000000],
    [3.467370000000000E-002, 14.4097000000000],
    [3.311310000000000E-002, 14.4753000000000],
    [3.162280000000000E-002, 14.5259000000000],
    [3.076000000000000E-002, 14.2333000000000],
    [2.884030000000000E-002, 14.0920000000000],
    [2.754230000000000E-002, 14.1720000000000],
    [2.630270000000000E-002, 14.2524000000000],
    [2.511890000000000E-002, 14.3335000000000],
    [2.398830000000000E-002, 14.4156000000000],
    [2.290870000000000E-002, 14.4939000000000],
    [2.200000000000000E-002, 14.5779000000000],
    [2.089300000000000E-002, 14.6682000000000],
    [1.995260000000000E-002, 14.7514000000000],
    [1.905460000000000E-002, 14.8331000000000],
    [1.819700000000000E-002, 14.9167000000000],
    [1.737800000000000E-002, 15.0014000000000],
    [1.659590000000000E-002, 15.0879000000000],
    [1.584890000000000E-002, 15.1767000000000],
    [1.513560000000000E-002, 15.2418000000000],
    [1.483000000000000E-002, 15.3328000000000],
    [1.380380000000000E-002, 15.4529000000000],
    [1.318260000000000E-002, 15.5480000000000],
    [1.258930000000000E-002, 15.6460000000000],
    [1.202260000000000E-002, 15.7458000000000],
    [1.148150000000000E-002, 15.8475000000000],
    [1.096480000000000E-002, 15.9519000000000],
    [1.047130000000000E-002, 16.0349000000000],
    [1.000000000000000E-002, 16.0371000000000],
    [9.549930000000000E-003, 15.7749000000000],
    [9.120110000000001E-003, 16.2558000000000],
    [8.709639999999999E-003, 16.4698000000000],
    [8.317639999999999E-003, 16.5205000000000],
    [7.943280000000000E-003, 16.6054000000000],
    [7.585780000000000E-003, 16.7348000000000],
    [7.244360000000000E-003, 16.8668000000000],
    [6.918310000000000E-003, 16.9453000000000],
    [6.606930000000000E-003, 17.0897000000000],
    [6.320000000000000E-003, 17.2350000000000],
    [6.025600000000000E-003, 17.3793000000000],
    [5.754400000000000E-003, 17.5246000000000],
    [5.495410000000000E-003, 17.6720000000000],
    [5.248070000000000E-003, 17.8119000000000],
    [5.011870000000000E-003, 17.8516000000000],
    [4.786300000000000E-003, 17.6419000000000],
    [4.570880000000000E-003, 17.9837000000000],
    [4.365160000000000E-003, 18.1039000000000],
    [4.168690000000000E-003, 18.3111000000000],
    [4.000000000000000E-003, 19.2196000000000],
    [3.801890000000000E-003, 18.7958000000000],
    [3.630780000000000E-003, 17.9111000000000],
    [3.467370000000000E-003, 17.6562000000000],
    [3.311310000000000E-003, 19.6190000000000],
    [3.162280000000000E-003, 19.0650000000000],
    [3.019950000000000E-003, 21.9542000000000],
    [2.884030000000000E-003, 19.5001000000000],
    [2.754230000000000E-003, 20.3540000000000],
    [2.630270000000000E-003, 19.9376000000000],
    [2.530000000000000E-003, 19.9919000000000],
    [2.398830000000000E-003, 21.9588000000000],
    [2.290870000000000E-003, 18.3449000000000],
    [2.187760000000000E-003, 20.3525000000000],
    [2.089300000000000E-003, 17.5126000000000],
    [1.995260000000000E-003, 18.4107000000000],
    [1.905460000000000E-003, 21.3591000000000],
    [1.819700000000000E-003, 23.3850000000000],
    [1.737800000000000E-003, 21.9107000000000],
    [1.659590000000000E-003, 21.9660000000000],
    [1.600000000000000E-003, 18.7184000000000],
    [1.513560000000000E-003, 19.0057000000000],
    [1.445440000000000E-003, 22.2523000000000],
    [1.380380000000000E-003, 22.0391000000000],
    [1.318260000000000E-003, 24.7504000000000],
    [1.258930000000000E-003, 19.5629000000000],
    [1.202260000000000E-003, 21.0009000000000],
    [1.148150000000000E-003, 26.9795000000000],
    [1.096480000000000E-003, 23.3514000000000],
    [1.047130000000000E-003, 25.8402000000000],
    [1.020000000000000E-003, 31.2600000000000],
    [9.549930000000000E-004, 22.5731000000000],
    [9.120110000000000E-004, 25.9437000000000],
    [8.709640000000000E-004, 18.5276000000000],
    [8.317640000000000E-004, 22.6921000000000],
    [7.943280000000000E-004, 21.0676000000000],
    [7.585780000000000E-004, 27.2406000000000],
    [7.244360000000000E-004, 19.8754000000000],
    [6.918310000000000E-004, 27.1134000000000],
    [6.500000000000000E-004, 23.0271000000000],
    [6.309570000000000E-004, 29.2659000000000],
    [6.025600000000000E-004, 31.2778000000000],
    [5.754400000000000E-004, 53.2253000000000],
    [5.495410000000000E-004, 49.8740000000000],
    [5.248080000000000E-004, 47.3487000000000],
    [5.011870000000001E-004, 18.9799000000000],
    [4.786300000000000E-004, 23.6182000000000],
    [4.570880000000000E-004, 28.2684000000000],
    [4.365160000000000E-004, 22.4503000000000],
    [4.110000000000000E-004, 38.9086000000000],
    [3.981070000000000E-004, 21.2037000000000],
    [3.801890000000000E-004, 22.3186000000000],
    [3.630780000000000E-004, 31.2419000000000],
    [3.467370000000000E-004, 41.5448000000000],
    [3.311310000000000E-004, 37.0971000000000],
    [3.162280000000000E-004, 45.1969000000000],
    [3.019950000000000E-004, 32.6585000000000],
    [2.884030000000000E-004, 74.8840000000000],
    [2.754230000000000E-004, 56.7376000000000],
    [2.600000000000000E-004, 70.3032000000000],
    [2.511890000000000E-004, 39.7010000000000],
    [2.398830000000000E-004, 50.9435000000000],
    [2.290870000000000E-004, 39.9715000000000],
    [2.187760000000000E-004, 25.2624000000000],
    [2.089300000000000E-004, 68.9951000000000],
    [1.995260000000000E-004, 57.2559000000000],
    [1.905460000000000E-004, 24.7486000000000],
    [1.819700000000000E-004, 27.3235000000000],
    [1.737800000000000E-004, 18.5383000000000],
    [1.690000000000000E-004, 74.1627000000000],
    [1.584890000000000E-004, 38.9836000000000],
    [1.513560000000000E-004, 44.9023000000000],
    [1.445440000000000E-004, 37.7732000000000],
    [1.380380000000000E-004, 64.7683000000000],
    [1.318260000000000E-004, 39.5053000000000],
    [1.258920000000000E-004, 32.3613000000000],
    [1.202260000000000E-004, 112.868000000000],
    [1.148150000000000E-004, 16.3039000000000],
    [1.100000000000000E-004, 95.7534000000000],
    [1.047130000000000E-004, 33.6910000000000],
    [1.000000000000000E-004, 54.1817000000000],
    [9.549930000000000E-005, 43.5069000000000],
    [9.120110000000000E-005, 127.336000000000],
    [8.709640000000000E-005, 204.869000000000],
    [8.317640000000001E-005, 47.1042000000000],
    [7.943280000000000E-005, 25.2095000000000],
    [7.585780000000000E-005, 300.232000000000],
    [7.244360000000000E-005, 19.9080000000000],
    [6.800000000000000E-005, 65.3654000000000],
    [6.606930000000000E-005, 170.164000000000],
    [6.309570000000000E-005, 56.7311000000000],
    [6.025600000000000E-005, 209.600000000000],
    [5.754400000000000E-005, 93.0060000000000],
    [5.495410000000000E-005, 216.067000000000],
    [5.248080000000000E-005, 91.9810000000000],
    [5.011870000000000E-005, 80.9733000000000],
    [4.786300000000000E-005, 50.5235000000000],
    [4.570880000000000E-005, 214.747000000000],
    [4.365160000000000E-005, 14.8949000000000],
    [4.200000000000000E-005, 147.988000000000],
    [3.981070000000000E-005, 9.20918000000000],
    [3.801890000000000E-005, 9.74462000000000],
    [3.630780000000000E-005, 24.1602000000000],
    [3.467370000000000E-005, 10.9305000000000],
    [3.311310000000000E-005, 27.4628000000000],
    [3.162280000000000E-005, 10.4523000000000],
    [3.019950000000000E-005, 10.7964000000000],
    [2.884030000000000E-005, 12.1316000000000],
    [2.754230000000000E-005, 78.0281000000000],
    [2.630270000000000E-005, 97.1881000000000],
    [2.500000000000000E-005, 15.9239000000000],
    [2.398830000000000E-005, 29.6469000000000],
    [2.290870000000000E-005, 337.513000000000],
    [2.187760000000000E-005, 18.0230000000000],
    [2.089300000000000E-005, 11.7263000000000],
    [1.995260000000000E-005, 12.5310000000000],
    [1.905460000000000E-005, 17.2370000000000],
    [1.819700000000000E-005, 373.057000000000],
    [1.737800000000000E-005, 32.3958000000000],
    [1.659590000000000E-005, 41.5677000000000],
    [1.584890000000000E-005, 119.295000000000],
    [1.500000000000000E-005, 722.037000000000],
    [1.445440000000000E-005, 217.137000000000],
    [1.380380000000000E-005, 30.5076000000000],
    [1.318260000000000E-005, 24.5398000000000],
    [1.258930000000000E-005, 47.6542000000000],
    [1.202260000000000E-005, 488.130000000000],
    [1.148150000000000E-005, 418.526000000000],
    [1.096480000000000E-005, 524.688000000000],
    [1.047130000000000E-005, 35.5262000000000],
    [1.000000000000000E-005, 18.2453000000000],
    [9.549930000000000E-006, 15.2203000000000],
    [9.099999999999999E-006, 15.3538000000000],
    [8.709640000000000E-006, 19.5034000000000],
    [8.317639999999999E-006, 77.2433000000000],
    [7.943279999999999E-006, 742.978000000000],
    [7.585780000000000E-006, 51.8944000000000],
    [7.244360000000000E-006, 24.9540000000000],
    [6.918310000000000E-006, 19.9021000000000],
    [6.606930000000000E-006, 18.0858000000000],
    [6.309570000000000E-006, 17.2909000000000],
    [6.025600000000000E-006, 16.9381000000000],
    [5.754400000000000E-006, 16.8156000000000],
    [5.500000000000000E-006, 16.8292000000000],
    [5.248080000000000E-006, 16.9383000000000],
    [5.011870000000000E-006, 17.1118000000000],
    [4.786300000000000E-006, 17.3355000000000],
    [4.570880000000000E-006, 17.6008000000000],
    [4.365160000000000E-006, 17.9025000000000],
    [4.168690000000000E-006, 18.2371000000000],
    [3.981070000000000E-006, 18.6025000000000],
    [3.801890000000000E-006, 18.9976000000000],
    [3.630780000000000E-006, 19.4212000000000],
    [3.467370000000000E-006, 19.8871000000000],
    [3.300000000000000E-006, 20.3715000000000],
    [3.162280000000000E-006, 20.8665000000000],
    [3.019950000000000E-006, 21.4128000000000],
    [2.884030000000000E-006, 21.9924000000000],
    [2.754230000000000E-006, 22.6077000000000],
    [2.630270000000000E-006, 23.2619000000000],
    [2.511890000000000E-006, 23.9565000000000],
    [2.398830000000000E-006, 24.6947000000000],
    [2.290870000000000E-006, 25.4809000000000],
    [2.187760000000000E-006, 26.3194000000000],
    [2.089300000000000E-006, 27.1909000000000],
    [2.000000000000000E-006, 28.1391000000000],
    [1.905460000000000E-006, 29.1900000000000],
    [1.819700000000000E-006, 30.2908000000000],
    [1.737800000000000E-006, 31.4791000000000],
    [1.659590000000000E-006, 32.7609000000000],
    [1.584890000000000E-006, 34.1370000000000],
    [1.513560000000000E-006, 35.6388000000000],
    [1.445440000000000E-006, 37.2799000000000],
    [1.380380000000000E-006, 39.0750000000000],
    [1.318260000000000E-006, 41.0459000000000],
    [1.258930000000000E-006, 43.2182000000000],
    [1.202260000000000E-006, 45.1100000000000],
    [1.170000000000000E-006, 47.7287000000000],
    [1.096480000000000E-006, 51.2749000000000],
    [1.047130000000000E-006, 54.6075000000000],
    [1.000000000000000E-006, 58.3847000000000],
    [9.549930000000000E-007, 62.6703000000000],
    [9.120110000000000E-007, 67.5613000000000],
    [8.709640000000000E-007, 73.1814000000000],
    [8.317640000000000E-007, 79.6746000000000],
    [7.943280000000000E-007, 87.2413000000000],
    [7.585780000000000E-007, 96.0973000000000],
    [7.244360000000000E-007, 108.010000000000],
    [6.840000000000000E-007, 120.754000000000],
    [6.606930000000000E-007, 134.132000000000],
    [6.309570000000000E-007, 152.460000000000],
    [6.025600000000000E-007, 174.985000000000],
    [5.754400000000000E-007, 203.087000000000],
    [5.495410000000000E-007, 238.530000000000],
    [5.248070000000000E-007, 283.928000000000],
    [5.011870000000000E-007, 342.937000000000],
    [4.786300000000000E-007, 421.199000000000],
    [4.570880000000000E-007, 527.048000000000],
    [4.365160000000000E-007, 673.141000000000],
    [4.168690000000000E-007, 866.182000000000],
    [4.000000000000000E-007, 1158.58000000000],
    [3.801890000000000E-007, 1608.23000000000],
    [3.630780000000000E-007, 2234.74000000000],
    [3.467370000000000E-007, 3097.72000000000],
    [3.311310000000000E-007, 4132.69000000000],
    [3.162280000000000E-007, 5051.31000000000],
    [3.019950000000000E-007, 5437.76000000000],
    [2.884030000000000E-007, 5140.50000000000],
    [2.754230000000000E-007, 4419.89000000000],
    [2.630270000000000E-007, 3626.20000000000],
    [2.511890000000000E-007, 2946.65000000000],
    [2.398830000000000E-007, 2439.16000000000],
    [2.300000000000000E-007, 2042.55000000000],
    [2.187760000000000E-007, 1733.09000000000],
    [2.089300000000000E-007, 1511.75000000000],
    [1.995260000000000E-007, 1342.76000000000],
    [1.905460000000000E-007, 1211.90000000000],
    [1.819700000000000E-007, 1109.21000000000],
    [1.737800000000000E-007, 1027.72000000000],
    [1.659590000000000E-007, 962.465000000000],
    [1.584890000000000E-007, 909.815000000000],
    [1.513560000000000E-007, 867.186000000000],
    [1.445440000000000E-007, 832.468000000000],
    [1.380380000000000E-007, 804.203000000000],
    [1.318260000000000E-007, 781.261000000000],
    [1.258920000000000E-007, 762.751000000000],
    [1.202260000000000E-007, 747.974000000000],
    [1.148150000000000E-007, 736.382000000000],
    [1.096480000000000E-007, 727.494000000000],
    [1.047130000000000E-007, 720.981000000000],
    [1.000000000000000E-007, 720.218000000000],
    [6.309570000000000E-008, 794.415000000000],
    [3.981070000000000E-008, 933.150000000000],
    [2.511890000000000E-008, 1130.68000000000],
    [1.584890000000000E-008, 1392.09000000000],
    [1.000000000000000E-008, 1729.08000000000],
    [6.309570000000000E-009, 2158.53000000000],
    [3.981070000000000E-009, 2702.93000000000],
    [2.511890000000000E-009, 3391.27000000000],
    [1.584890000000000E-009, 4259.64000000000]
];

var options1 = {
    lines: {
        show: true
    },
    yaxis: {
        panRange: [0, 6000]
    },
    xaxis: {
        panRange: [0, 20],
        ticks: [0.00000001, 0.0000001, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0],
        transform: function (v) {
            return Math.log(v);
        },
        inverseTransform: function (v) {
            return Math.exp(v);
        },
    },
    zoom: {
        interactive: true
    },

    pan: {
        interactive: true
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1], options1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.selection.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:800px;height:600px;"></div>
```